# What can I do to generate random samples from a distribution of data that I have?

Tags: python, numpy, distribution, sampling

I have data on the amount of minutes that a machine is active. From this data I get the following distribution plot with minutes on the x axis and the count on the y axis:

[image]

Now I want to create a simulation where the time the machine is active is randomly drawn from this distribution, only I have no idea how to do this. Instinctually I would say that I need to use `random.expovariate()`, however I have no idea what value I would use as lambda.

Anyone have any ideas?

The data I have is:

```
randomlist = ([ 0.,  1., 11.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  5.,  5.,  2.,  7.,  8.,  4.,  4.,
        4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  7.,  4.,  4., 18., 14., 13.,  4.,  1., 10.,
        6.,  5.,  4.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  6.,  4.,  6., 17.,  6.,  2.,  4.,
        7., 17., 19., 18.,  4.,  9.,  4.,  7.,  4., 14., 12.,  4.,  3.,
        2.,  8.,  8.,  7.,  4.,  7.,  6.,  3.,  6.,  6., 13.,  2., 16.,
        6.,  4.,  6., 11., 10.,  6., 10.,  9.,  4.,  9.,  4.,  9.,  1.,
        5.,  4., 10.,  8.,  8.,  7.,  3., 20., 12.,  5.,  1., 11.,  8.,
        5.,  5.,  9.,  1.,  5.,  2., 12.,  3.,  6.,  3.,  4.,  8.,  1.,
        3.,  1., 14.,  5.,  4., 20.,  4., 11.,  3.,  9., 14., 37.,  4.,
       19., 31., 20., 11., 28.,  8., 16.,  5., 15.,  1.,  3., 11., 30.,
        4.,  8.,  4., 28.,  2.,  1., 22.,  1., 74.,  7., 22.,  5.,  7.,
        5.,  3.,  2.,  7.,  8., 19., 37.,  8.,  4.,  1., 12.,  3., 18.,
       11.,  7., 30.,  4., 13.,  6.,  5.,  4.,  1.,  4.,  4.,  6.,  9.,
       45.,  1.,  1.,  5.,  4.,  2.,  5.,  1.,  3.,  2., 12., 35., 33.,
        3., 20.,  4., 10.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  6.,  8.,  7.,
       11.,  3.,  7.,  2., 15.,  4.,  7., 16., 22., 38.,  8., 12.,  4.,
        5.,  2.,  6., 18.,  2.,  6., 60.,  3., 16., 10., 59.,  4.,  4.,
       15., 55.,  6., 23.,  1.,  2.,  6., 58.,  1., 18.,  2.,  3.,  2.,
       34.,  6.,  1.,  3.,  7., 13.,  1.,  5.,  5., 14.,  6., 19.,  1.,
       37.,  6., 11., 50.,  6.,  5., 29., 17.,  9.,  8., 17.,  8.,  9.,
        7.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  9.,  9.,  1.,  8.,  5., 16.,  7.,  9., 12.,
        5.,  3., 15.,  1.,  3.,  2., 18.,  6., 15., 24., 34.,  3.,  3.,
       12.,  1., 29., 16., 13., 12.,  3., 15.,  7.,  9.,  9., 10.,  3.,
       37.,  2., 10.,  4.,  8.,  1.,  8., 31.,  5.,  1.,  5., 19., 12.,
       41.,  5.,  6.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  4.,  8.,  5., 14.,  9.,  6.,  6.,
        4.,  9.,  3.,  3.,  7., 10., 14., 13., 15.,  7., 14., 31.,  6.,
        3., 19., 16., 33.,  6.,  4.,  2., 16.,  1., 18., 10., 24., 14.,
        7.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  6.,  2.,  2., 14.,  8.,  3.,  5., 37.,  6.,
        6.,  9., 21., 23.,  4.,  6., 18., 16., 23.,  3.,  9.,  4.,  9.,
        5.,  1.,  6.,  1.,  1., 23.,  8.,  6.,  1., 33.,  4.,  3., 15.,
        5.,  9., 27., 17.,  7.,  4.,  9., 47.,  7.,  6.,  4., 30.,  4.,
       27., 13., 22., 12.,  2., 21., 13.,  9.,  6., 14.,  5.,  7., 18.,
        7.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  4., 10.,  1.,  5.,  9.])
```

Comment: use `random.choice` https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_choice.asp

Comment: That is definitely a solution, but the notebook will get very convoluted this way. I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: if you have the original data, then picking directly from it will give you samples following the distribution. what do you mean the notebook will get very convoluted?

Comment: Maybe convoluted is the wrong word (english is not my mother tongue). Adding the list as is will make it quite a lengthy notebook if I need to do this for 10 machines.

Comment: But in the question you literally give us the data you have. you just need to do `random.choice(randomlist)`. You mean that you will not have `randomlist` in your real code? Then provide us with the code and variables you have.

Comment: The randomlist data is from another source. I will have to create a new notebook for my simulation. I could of course just add this data as is and use `random.choice()` but thought there would be another way. thanks for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) allows you to provide weights

```
import random
from collections import Counter

randomList = [...]
c = Counter(randomlist)
num_samples = 100
print(random.choices(list(c.keys()), weights=list(c.values()), k=num_samples))
```

In my example I'm calculating weights from your `randomList` but you could pre-calculate offline if you don't want to do it in your script.

Comment: If you want to sample from a continuous variable, i.e. fractional minutes, [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559616/how-to-sample-from-a-distribution-given-the-cdf-in-python) could be useful

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use `np.random.expovariate()` that implies an assumption about your data being exponentially distributed. If you are happy with that, you can use the Scipy library to fit an exponential function and deduce your rate parameter. Good step-by-step instructions can be find eg. [here](https://ipython-books.github.io/75-fitting-a-probability-distribution-to-data-with-the-maximum-likelihood-method/).

Alternatively, as suggested above, just use `np.random.choice()`